# Clojure calling Bytes from hbase-utils returns a non-type-matching result

Tags: java, hadoop, clojure, hbase, byte

There is a function

`(defn ->bytes [x]
  (Bytes/toBytes x))`

where `Bytes` comes from the Apache Hbase Client Utils: `(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util Bytes)` from `[org.apache.hbase/hbase-shaded-client "1.2.0"]`

calling `(seq (->bytes (long 10))) => (0 0 0 10)`
but calling `(seq (Bytes/toBytes (long 10))) => (0 0 0 0 0 0 0 10)`

I tried to print the type of `x` inside `->bytes` and saw it was still java.lang.long.

Totally confused, could not figure out what's wrong.

---

Update:

This seems to be a problem that is probabilty triggered, everything worked fine as I restarted the REPL, but worked weird again when I restarted the REPL again.....

---

Update:

`(seq (->bytes (Long/MAX_VALUE))) => (-1 -1 -1 -1)`

Comment: `(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util Bytes)` is from `[org.apache.hbase/hbase-shaded-client "1.2.0"]`

Comment: `(seq (Bytes/toBytes (Long. 10)))` gives me `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: More than one matching method found: toBytes`. Is this exactly the code you are using?

Comment: Try using `(long 10)`instead of `(Long. 10)` ?

Comment: I have removed my answer, as you have found the root cause in another SO question.